# Swift 2: Unexpectedly writing to a property when trying to read it

Tags: swift2, xcode7

The problem I'm having is that my property's `willSet` and `didSet` are being called even though I'm *only reading the property*, and this breaks my app.

I condensed my problem into a playground. Uncomment `#1` to see the problem, or `#2` to see the expected behavior.

#### What's going on here?

```
protocol Departure
{
    var line: String? { get }
}

class MyDeparture : Departure
{
    var line: String? = "SomeString"
}

#if true
    // #1: this causes a write to tableContet later (!)
    typealias TableSection = (title: String, rows: [Departure])
    #else
    // #2: this doesn't cause a write to tableContent later
    typealias TableSection = (title: String, rows: [MyDeparture])
#endif

var tableContent: [TableSection] = [ TableSection(title: "MySectionTitle", rows: [ MyDeparture() ]) ]
{
willSet { print("willSet tableContent") }
didSet { print("didSet tableContent") }
}

func getDepartureDescription() -> String? {
    print("start getDepartureDescription")
    defer { print("end getDepartureDescription") }

    #if true
        // writes to tableContent in case #1
        let lineNumber = tableContent[0].rows[0].line
        #else
        // never writes to table content
        let row = tableContent[0].rows[0]
        let lineNumber = row.line
    #endif

    return "Your line is \(lineNumber)"
}

getDepartureDescription()
```

This prints

> start getDepartureDescription
> willSet tableContent
> didSet tableContent
> end getDepartureDescription

I'm using Xcode 7 (7A218) GM seed. Everything worked as expected in Xcode 6.4 and Swift 1.2.

---

Side note:

At first I thought that the runtime was--on reading `TableSection.rows`--creating a new `[Departure]` array from the `[MyDeparture]` array that was assigned to it. But even correcting for that in the most explicit way I could think of didn't get rid of the problem:

```
// More correct types makes no difference:
var departures: [Departure] {
    var result = Array<Departure>()
    result.append(MyDeparture())
    return result
}

var tableContent: [TableSection] = [ TableSection(title: "MyTitle", rows:  departures ) ]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's some sort of lazy initialisation going on. It's only when it gets to the line

```
let lineNumber = tableContent[0].rows[0].line
```

that the run time seems to be filling in the contents of the array.

If you declared the array as containing elements that conform to the `Departure` protocol, the runtime does not know how big the elements of `tableContent` actually are because both classes and structs can conform to `Departure`. Hence, I think it is recreating the array and triggering `didSet` and `willSet` erroneously.

I tried limiting your protocol to classes like so:

```
protocol Departure: class
{
    var line: String? { get }
}
```

and the problem goes away because now the runtime knows the array can only contain class references.

I think this is a bug and you should raise it with Apple.

Comment: Good idea for a workaround. I updated my code to underline exactly where it breaks (reading `line`). Looks like a bug, because both branches in the second `#if` should have the same result.